# What is the criteria for a woman to see another woman?

Tags: halal-haram, hijab

What is the criteria for a woman to see another woman ?

Comment: The question, as it is, is unclear and vague. What do you mean "see"?

Comment: In a front of a non mahram man a woman can reveal only her face and hand so in front of a woman what parts of  body can she reveal?